# Understanding function referencing in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have been learning JavaScript for sometime now via the HeadFirst JavaScript book.

On page 440 of the book, the below code is called. I have provided everything on this page here.

```
var winner = function() { console.log("WINNER!") };
var loser = function() { console.log("LOSER!") };
// let's test as a warm up
winner();
// let's assign to other variables for practice
var a = winner;
var b = loser;
var c = loser;
a();
b();
// now let's try your luck with a shell game
c = a;                    //[1]
console.log("c is: " + c);// winner
a = b;                    //[2]
console.log("a is: " + a);// loser
b = c;                    //[3]
console.log("b is: " + b);// loser
c = a;                    //[4]
console.log("c is: " + c);// winner
a = c;                    //[5]
console.log("a is: " + a);// loser
a = b;                    //[6]
console.log("a is: " + a);// loser
b = c;                    //[7]
console.log("b is: " + b);// loser
a();
```

My issue is, I know that the `=` operator assigns, so my expected answers are those commented out with `//`. I am confused with some of the results since they overide my previous knowledge of the `=` operator function.

For example `c=a` in [1] should bring 'WINNER' because in my understanding the `c` variable has been assigned to `a` variable which is 'winner' and thus the end result should be 'WINNER'. This understanding worked [2] which resulted in 'LOSER' but from then on it was all south. Take [4] for example, I thought `c=a` would return 'WINNER' but it instead returned 'LOSER'. I though `c` variable being assigned to `a` would turn to 'winner' since the latter is `a = winner` but instead returned `LOSER`. I am kind of confused what's happening here. See the results below, the words after '//' were my expected answers but this is what the console returned.

```
WINNER!
WINNER!
LOSER!
--------from here ----------------
c is: function() { console.log("WINNER!") }
a is: function() { console.log("LOSER!") }
b is: function() { console.log("WINNER!") }
c is: function() { console.log("LOSER!") }
a is: function() { console.log("LOSER!") }
a is: function() { console.log("WINNER!") }
b is: function() { console.log("LOSER!") }
WINNER!
```

I would appreciate if you would explain to me the logic behind the answers from [3] downwards.

Comment: `Take [4] for example, I thought c=a would return 'WINNER' but it instead returned 'LOSER'. I though c variable being assigned to a would turn to 'winner' since the latter is a = winner but instead returned LOSER.` No, `a` is __not__ winner as can be seen two lines earlier.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the concept of reassignment?

Comment: @programandoconro so I should go with the value of what the variable `a` 'b` or `c` was last assigned with, rather than what was hardcoded as `var a = winner;` , `var b = loser;`, `var c = loser;` in the early beginning?

Comment: `var` means that the value can be changed, so it **can** become _something other than what it was at first_. If you used `const`, you cannot re-assign it. Actually, if you try to re-assign a constant, it will throw an error before you can finish your program.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to keep track of the values using a table:

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Before [1] | winner | loser | loser |
| After [1] (c=a) | winner | loser | winner |
| After [2] (a=b) | loser | loser | winner |
| After [3] (b=c) | loser | winner | winner |
| After [4] (c=a) | loser | winner | loser |
| After [5] (a=c) | loser | winner | loser |
| After [6] (a=b) | winner | winner | loser |
| After [7] (b=c) | winner | loser | loser |

So, in the end `a()` prints `WINNER!`

---

As for the differences with your expectations:

Take [3] as an example. As noted after `//` in your post, you expected `b` to become `loser`, but here it actually becomes `winner`.
That's because `b = c` uses the value of `c` at that moment. Note that `c` was previously re-assigned in to `winner` in [1], and at that moment it's still `winner`. 
So, after [3], `b` also refers to `winner`.

The other results can be explained in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

I think thanks to @programandoconro and @qrsngky, I should go with what a variable, in this case `a`, `b`, or `c` was last assigned (think of reassignment). For example, if `c` became winner in step [1], it retains the value `WINNER!` all through out until it turns to loser when it is assigned to `a` in step [4] where it turns to loser. I guess I should have in mind that the code is being read from top to bottom, and any changes conducted along the way remain so and affect other variables occuring below it.

I did a rerun of the same exercise and this time, without looking, I guessed the answers as depicted by the comment `///`. From the answers, turns out like I sort of got the concept (hopefully).

```
// now let's try your luck with a shell game
c = a; 
console.log("c is: " + c); /// c is winner
a = b; 
console.log("a is: " + a); /// a is loser
b = c; 
console.log("b is: " + b); /// b is winner
c = a; 
console.log("c is: " + c); /// c is loser
a = c; 
console.log("a is: " + a); /// a is loser
a = b; 
console.log("a is: " + a); /// a is winner
b = c; 
console.log("b is: " + b); /// b is loser
a();    /// WINNER!
```

Here were my answers. It seems they corroborated well with my above comments.

```
c is: function() { console.log("WINNER!") }
a is: function() { console.log("LOSER!") }
b is: function() { console.log("WINNER!") }
c is: function() { console.log("LOSER!") }
a is: function() { console.log("LOSER!") }
a is: function() { console.log("WINNER!") }
b is: function() { console.log("LOSER!") }
WINNER!
```